# ¿Solucion a java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Estoy tratando de cargar una escena para poder iniciar la aplicación usando este código:

```
public void start(Stage stage2) throws Exception {
       
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/interfaz/pruebaListView.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
        
        Parent root = loader.load();
        stage = stage2;
        scene = new Scene(root); 
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMinWidth(330);
        stage.setMinHeight(350);
        stage.show();
        
    }
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2523)
    at javafxmlapplication.JavaFXMLApplication.start(JavaFXMLApplication.java:36)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
```

Parece ser que no encuentra el fxml para cargar, pero no entiendo por qué ya que el archivo está donde se lo indico y se llama así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo con el loader es el de JavaFXMLApplication.

Edit: curiosamente si lo ejecuto en vscode funciona bien.

Comment: El gran problema que veo aquí es una pésima organización de directorios y de archivos. Lo grave no es tanto que no funcione en desarrollo, sino que en producción, si no hilas fino con tu estructura de directorios y tu código, algunos archivos podrían ser no encontrados en el programa final y eso sería catastrófico. Te aconsejo que reconsideres la forma en que estás organizando tus archivos. Mira por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24948550/5587982). Si organizas bien tus archivos, podrás encontrar los recursos con algo como esto ...

Comment: `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(JavaFXMLApplication.class.getResource("view/pruebaListView.fxml"));` en caso de haber seguido la estructura mostrada en la respuesta del enlace en mi anterior comentario. Y eso no te dará ningún problema tampoco en la App distribuida. Observa también allí dónde están los controladores y demás. En la captura de imagen de tu pregunta está todo mezclado.

Comment: He organizado mejor los ficheros y nada, sigue saltando el error

Comment: ¿Podrías  mostrar cómo está ahora el árbol de directorios? Es importante que uses correctamente los nombres de paquete. En la carpeta del proyecto tendrías un folder `src/main` y dentro de `main` un directorio `java` para todos los archivos java del proyecto y otro directorio `resources` para todos los recursos. Y, tanto en `java` como en `resources` todo organizado en la ruta `com.example.nombreProyecto` cambiando cada cosa por como se llaman para ti.

Comment: No sé como subir imágenes aquí, pero te dejo una carpeta de google donde he puesto como está actualmente el árbol:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Us9RLwORDQbrviLDZJNAguaYHbrve6R-?usp=sharing
También he puesto cómo está la creación del loader

Answer (score 4):

El gran problema que veo aquí es una pésima organización de directorios y de archivos. Lo grave no es tanto que no funcione en desarrollo, sino que en producción, si no hilas fino con tu estructura de directorios y tu código, algunos archivos podrían ser no encontrados en el programa final y eso sería catastrófico. Te aconsejo que reconsideres la forma en que estás organizando tus archivos.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo, observa la captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenemos una carpeta llamada `demoFXMaven202305` que es la que contiene todos los archivos del proyecto.

Dentro de esa carpeta tenemos otra carpeta `src`, dentro de `src` una carpeta `main` y dentro de `main` dos carpetas, una llamada `java` para todos los archivos `.java` y otra `resources` para todos los recursos: archivos `.xml, .fxml, .css, .txt, .jpg` etc.

OJO a esto: dentro de `java` y de `resources`, los archivos se organizan siguiendo la notación del nombre de paquete. Es decir, si tu aplicación tiene este nombre de paquete: `com.example.nombreAplicacion` vas a tener dentro de ambas carpetas ese mismo orden, y a partir de ahí ya pones tus archivos, que pueden ir en sub-carpetas, por ejemplo, en `resources` hay una sub-carpeta llamada `view` para los archivos `.fxml`.

El árbol de directorios final será más o menos así:

```
├── demoFXMaven202305
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── java
│   │       │   └── com
│   │       │       └── example
│   │       │           └── demoFXMaven202305
│   │       │               ├── HelloApplication.java
│   │       │               ├── HelloController.java
│   │       └── resources
│   │           └── com
│   │               └── example
│   │                   └── demoFXMaven202305
│   │                       └── view
│   │                           ├── hello-view.fxml
```

Es una estructura lo más simple posible, para no enredarte demasiado, pero una vez entendido el concepto puedes anidar, creando por ejemplo dentro de `java` o de `resources` otras sub-carpetas, tales como `controllers`, `utils`, `css`, `images`, etc.

Con esa organización, puedes llamar a los recursos con esto simplemente:

```
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("view/hello-view.fxml"));
```

He usado los nombres de mi ejemplo, en tu caso, cambia `HelloApplication` por el nombre de la clase donde está el punto de entrada de tu aplicación y cambia `hello-view` por el nombre del archivo `.fxml` que quieres cargar.

Si organizas el código así, cuando empaquetes la aplicación para distribuirla, tendrás algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no habrá problemas para encontrar los archivos.

Comment: Buenas, soy bastante nuevo en java y no he entendido muy bien esto:
 "Es decir, si tu aplicación tiene este nombre de paquete: com.example.nombreAplicacion"
Mi aplicación se llama Greenball ¿Debería ser entonces com.example.GreenBall?

Comment: @Ardust`com.example`eso es un ejemplo. Imagina que tu App está representada por una página web que es `greenball.com`, entonces el nombre de paquete de tu aplicación podía ser: `com.greenball`y partiendo de ahí vas nombrando. Dentro de ese paquete tú puedes crear varias aplicaciones o una sola, depende. Imagina el ejemplo de `Apple`, el nombre de paquete global sería `com.apple` y varias aplicaciones: `com.apple.quicktime`, `com.apple.tv`, `com.apple.mac`. [Revisa la doc de Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Era la base de datos. Hay un objeto que se llama "Booking" con un atributo de fecha que no se había guardado bien y saltaba.